# Return Last Value of a Row - EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
    A     B      C     D     E
1  20     30     40   50   60
```

Good Morning, I have an Excel Table as shown Above.

I want to return in another Cell the last value of this Row that is NOT NULL

So, my return would be 60

if some value is added latter, it would change:

```
    A     B      C     D     E     F
1  20     30     40   50    60    70
```

Now it would return 70

Tried to do by myself and tried to google it, did not find anything that works...

Could anybody help-me?

Comment: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COUNTA(1:1)))`

Comment: Just wondering if values would always increase in value? If so, maybe just `=MAX(1:1)`?

Comment: @JvdV They dont... they may decrease....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1E+99,1:1))
```

Or

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),1:1)
```